# Tag excerpt not showing up for synonym: why?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

As I was tagging [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22989/shaping-the-shape-tag) yesterday, I added [tags](/questions/tagged/tags), and I saw this:

[image]

So I thought the [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) had no info, and noted it in a "BTW" sentence at the end of the question. I removed it a while ago as per Martin's suggestion, since it was unrelated to the question. Before the suggestion, though, Martin (in [this comment exchange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEBxk.png) which we will now likely clean up) noted the info was present. My guess here is that the info did not show up because [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) is a synonym for [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging), and the info only shows up on the main tag. Is that true? And why is that so? Wouldn't it be better if the info showed up on synonyms too, or at least taggers were notified of the tags they are choosing being a synonym so they can look (if they wish) at the info on the main tag?

PS Curiously enough, I just tried to tag this [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) and that thing didn't show up, whereas [tag-management](/questions/tagged/tag-management) did, with "also:tag-management" at the end. Was [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) made a synonym of [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) only recently perhaps?

Comment: The comment exchange which you mention in your post is also archived [here in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/4/9).

Comment: [meta-tag:tags] was made a synonym of [meta-tag:tagging] in August 2010. Coincidentally, [meta-tag:tag-synonyms] was made a synonym of [meta-tag:tag-management] exactly two years ago.

Comment: It is strange that when trying to do the same thing we see different outcomes: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IgfUW.png (Although I cannot be sure that I was doing exactly what you did.)

Comment: The only difference seems to be I was doing it on a question already tagged [meta-tag:tagging], hence you see that tag showig up, I don't. Otherwise it seems to me that the outcomes are the same @Martin.